# Azure Data Explorer : Data Load Performance

Tags: azure-data-explorer

We are loading file of 100+GB into Azure Data Explorer using ADF's copy activity and it takes more than 13+ hours.

Is there any best practice to make the load in reasonable time frame ?

Answer (score 1):

what is the source of the data ? if it Azure Storage and less than 5,000 blobs/files please use 1click to ingest the data from storage - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/one-click-ingestion-new-table
if there is more than 5000 blobs/files = please use ingest historian data to ADX - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/generate-lightingest-command

Comment: Source of the data is ADLS Gen1/2, and it is text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can break it into two activities:

1. Use ADF to break this file into files that are ~1GB in size, writing them into a container on Azure storage.
2. Using another activity or using the methods in the answer above, ingest them into Azure Data Explorer.

You are also welcome to open a support ticket as the current behavior looks wrong.

Comment: in case you use ADF to split the 100GB file into smaller files (less than 1GB), please consider to use one click to ingest the files afterwards. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/one-click-ingestion-new-table

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, check the CPU consumption of your cluster during ingestion. By enabling the autoscale (Scale out), you may reduce the loading time in some cases.